# Increase your Prius battery capacity?

Tags: battery

There's a lot of info about Prius battery upgrades hidden in web forums, but I would like to bring some of that to SE.

What are some of the easiest ways to hook up aftermarket batteries to your Prius?

Comment: The question fails to note that Prius has actually two batteries, the 12V LV lead acid battery and the HV nickel metal hydride battery. The question seems to be about replacing the HV nickel metal hydride battery with something else.

Answer (score 2):

One could install a Lithium battery instead of a NiMH ( nickel-metal Hydride )

http://www.tgdaily.com/trendwatch-features/34422-tg-video-aftermarket-lithium-ion-battery-pack-squeezes-150-mpg-from-a-toyo

It costs $9500 and takes 4 hours to install.

Comment: Depending where you live, you may be illegally evading taxes by doing this. There is a reason why gasoline has a tax (to pay for building and maintaining roads). Usually, electric vehicles have some kinds of additional taxes as well so that EV owners can't avoid paying for road building and maintenance. Needless to say, it'll also void your warranty.